# Button Visibility Binding doesn't update

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm

I have a button on my Xaml page that its visibility is binded to a variable of Type : `SYSTEM.Windows.Visibility` in the view model, for the first time the page is loaded whether I set the variable to Hidden or Visible , it works fine. but aftre doing some operation when I change the variable to other status my GUI doesn't update.

Here are my xaml and MVVM

```
<Button Content="Extend" Name="btnExtend" Command="{Binding ExtendCommand}" Visibility="{Binding isVisible}"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="80" Margin="0,0,100,0" Height="25"/>
```

and view model :

```
Public Property isVisible As System.Windows.Visibility

Public Sub New()
        isVisible = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible
End Sub

Public Sub diable()
        isVisible = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible
End Sub
```

I read in some topics to change the variable to `Boolean` and use a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` , I tried this too, but the result was the same.

I really don't get it what I do wrong.

Comment: ... and where is the propertychanged event being fired?

Comment: Should I? because for binding text or other properties everything works just fine without fire any property changed.

Comment: Yes you should. You have to notify the view about property changed. I will post you an answer with links.

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check those links out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

http://www.daedtech.com/wpf-and-notifying-property-change

Tell your view that a property was changed by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Answer (score 5):

your xaml code should be

```
<Button Content="Extend" Name="btnExtend" Command="{Binding ExtendCommand}" Visibility="{Binding isVisible,Mode=Twoway}"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="80" Margin="0,0,100,0" Height="25"/>
```

and your Viewmodel Code Should be

```
  private Visibility _isVisible ;

public Visibility isVisible 
{
    get { return _isVisible ;}
    set { _isVisible  = value;RaisePropertyChanged("isVisible ");}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fire a OnPropertyChanged() event in the setter of the Public Property to notify your changes to UI. Viewing your code, I seems that you are missing the OnPorpertyChanged() event implementation.

An another approach can be boolean values. Instead of make Visibility property, create a Boolean property and write a converter named "BooleanToVisibility" which will convert the value of "Visibility" Dependency Property.

Define Converter as a Static Resource in ResourceDictionary and then you can use it throughout the application. Converter approach is good to avoid rewriting show/hide logic in each view model.

Please let me know if you need working example on Converters.